# Rails 3 migrations: Adding reference column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

If I create a new rails 3 migration with (for example)

```
rails g migration tester title:tester user:references
```

, everything works fine...however if I add a column with something along the lines of:

```
rails g migration add_user_to_tester user:references
```

the reference field is not recognised. In short, the question is: how do I add a referencing column to a rails migration from the command line?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

If you are using the **Rails 4.x** you can now generate migrations with references, like this:

```
rails generate migration AddUserRefToProducts user:references
```

like you can see on [rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

Comment: See section 2.1 from http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html for example.

Comment: how do you specify a column name for the foreign key instead the auto generated name?

Comment: @jwill you can use polymorphic: user:references{polymorphic}.

Comment: @PauloFidalgo Can you explain a bit about how to do that? may be some guide of links? (talking about polymorphic)

Comment: @Anwar: here are the docs http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-references

Answer (score 186):

**EDIT**: This is an outdated answer and should not be applied for **Rails 4.x+**

You don't need to add references when you can use an integer id to your referenced class.

I'd say the advantage of using references instead of a plain integer is that the model will be predefined with belongs_to and since the model is already created and will not be affected when you migrate something existing, the purpose is kind of lost.

So I would do like this instead:

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_tester user_id:integer
```

And then manually add belongs_to :user in the Tester model

Comment: But that won't create the appropriate foreign key constraints on databases that support it, right?

Comment: No, afaik Rails never create foreign key restraints on the database unless you add plugins to do it for you.

Comment: just studying this post, pls how do i add the reference after all

Comment: The way I showed does add a reference. But instead of it being a one line generator, it also requires you to add the reference code into your existing model, which is also included in the answer

Comment: remember to add the index with user:integer:index

Comment: This answer is really good, but I'm not sure I understand it fully due to the confusing grammar (multiple 'and' and 'since'. not sure where sentences end and start.)

"the model will be predefined with belongs_to and since the model is already created and will not be affected when you migrate something existing, the purpose is kind of lost."

Comment: What should i do if the user model is like, `Subscription::User` so how will i write the migration for this?

Comment: Answer is dated, see @Paulo's answer for modern rails.

Comment: @abahgat with Rails > 4.2 there is now an ```add_foreign_key``` method which facilitates adding a fk constraint at the db level

Answer (score 103):

Please note that you will most likely need an index on that column too.

```
class AddUserReferenceToTester < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :testers, :user_id, :integer
    add_index  :testers, :user_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Why? Is this true for most belongs_to relationships?

Comment: It is indeed for performance reasons and comes in handy if you have a has_many/has_one on the other side of that belongs_to relation. If you are absolutely sure that you will not go through `user.testers` you can omit the index.

Comment: The `rails g migration ...` generated `add_reference :installs, :device, index: true` which also creates the index.

Answer (score 49):

With the two previous steps stated above, you're still missing the foreign key constraint. This should work:

```
  class AddUserReferenceToTester < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
          add_column :testers, :user_id, :integer, references: :users
      end
  end
```

Comment: This is the only actual answer here. The foreign key is the most critical part here

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer since the questions asks for rails 3

Answer (score 35):

You *can* use references in a change migration. This is valid Rails 3.2.13 code:

```
class AddUserToTester < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :testers do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true 
    end
  end
  def down
    change_table :testers do |t|
      t.remove :user_id
    end
  end
end
```

c.f.: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_table

Comment: change and down methods? aren't up and down methods instead?

Comment: @MaicolBen yes, and you can also just leave off the down method.

Comment: @MaicolBen Without the `down` method, I got `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration` when rolling back using Rails 3.2. I also had to change `change` to `up`.

Answer (score 27):

Running `rails g migration AddUserRefToSponsors user:references` will generate the following migration:

```
def change
  add_reference :sponsors, :user, index: true
end
```

Comment: Which version of Rails is this for?

Answer (score 8):

When adding a column you need to make that column an integer and if possible stick with rails conventions. So for your case I am assuming you already have a Tester and User models, and testers and users tables.

To add the foreign key you need to create an integer column with the name user_id (convention):

```
add_column :tester, :user_id, :integer
```

Then add a belongs_to to the tester model:

```
class Tester < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And you might also want to add an index for the foreign key (this is something the references already does for you):

```
add_index :tester, :user_id
```

Answer (score 8):

That will do the trick:

```
rails g migration add_user_to_tester user_id:integer:index
```

Comment: I like that this also adds the index that you will most likely want.

Answer (score 3):

You can add references to your model through command line in the following manner:

```
rails g migration add_column_to_tester user_id:integer
```

This will generate a migration file like :

```
class AddColumnToTesters < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :testers, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

This works fine every time i use it..

Answer (score 3):

**For Rails 4**

The generator accepts column type as references (also available as `belongs_to`).

This migration will create a `user_id` column and appropriate index:

```
$ rails g migration AddUserRefToProducts user:references
```

generates:

```
class AddUserRefToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :products, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration

**For Rails 3**

Helper is called references (also available as `belongs_to`).

This migration will create a `category_id` column of the appropriate type. Note that you pass the model name, not the column name. Active Record adds the `_id` for you.

```
change_table :products do |t|
  t.references :category
end
```

If you have polymorphic `belongs_to` associations then references will add both of the columns required:

```
change_table :products do |t|
  t.references :attachment, :polymorphic => {:default => 'Photo'}
end
```

Will add an attachment_id column and a string `attachment_type` column with a default value of `Photo`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration