# SQLException: near "references": syntax error: ALTER TABLE "questions" ADD "video" references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, sqlexception

I tried "`AddvideoToQuestions video: references"`

A question has_many videos. A video belongs_to a question.

Tried to rake `db:migrate`, and got the following error.

WHATSUP? I'm finally deep diving into coding in rails (my first real language), and this bug has been getting to me.

> SQLite3::SQLException: near "references": syntax error: ALTER TABLE
>   "questions" ADD "video"
>   references/Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `initialize'

@Marek Lipka -- tried that and tried rake `db:migrate` again, but still the same error.

Below is the log:

(Apologies -- not familiar with how to present code blocks.

> QLite3::SQLException: near "references": syntax error: ALTER TABLE
>   "questions" ADD "video"
>   references/Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `initialize'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`
>   new'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `prepare'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in`
>   execute'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:278:in
>   `block in execute'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in`block in log'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in
>   `instrument'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in`log'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:278:in
>   `execute'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:264:in`
>   add_column'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:400:in
>   `add_column'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in`block in method_missing'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in`say_with_time'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
>   /Users/davidngo/Desktop/Coding/RoR_Practice/videxpert/db/migrate/20130809091631_add_video_to_question.rb:3:in`
>   change'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in`block in migrate'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:119:in
>   `with_connection'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in`migrate'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in`block (2 levels) in migrate'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in`block in ddl_transaction'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in
>   `transaction'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in`transaction'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in`block in migrate'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in`migrate'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in`migrate'
>   /Users/davidngo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:153:in
>   `block (2 levels) in '

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bundle exec rails g migration add_video_to_questions video:references
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was already answered in:
[Rails 3 migrations: Adding reference column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954969/rails-3-migrations-adding-reference-column)

That being said, I had a similar issue.
I cannot tell you what exactly is going wrong, but here is how I got past the issue:

rails g migration add_video_id_to_questions video_id:integer