# Undefined method 'add_reference'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to add a user reference to my post tables with following code:

```
class AddUserIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :posts, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

but I've received an error message:

```
undefined method 'add_reference'
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

I'm using Rails 3.2.13

Comment: this might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954969/rails-3-migrations-adding-reference-column

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Rails 3 you must do it like so

```
class AddUserIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :posts, :user_id
  end
end
```

Only in Rails 4 you can do it the way you posted.

Comment: Thank you Luis, I didn't know that this method was valid only in Rails 4

Answer (score 3):

add_reference is specific to rails 4.0.0, so you should try this instead :

```
class AddUserIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :posts, :user_id
  end
end
```

this is a great [post](http://srbiv.github.io/2103/06/20/rails-4-add_reference-method.html) about this subject

Answer (score 3):

Your migration should be

```
rails generate migration AddUserRefToPosts user:references
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
def change
  change_table :posts do |p|
    p.references :user, index: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This method apperead in Rails 4.0

I think you may create some monkey patch with this functionality for Rails 3.2