# Rails association with models and migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, ruby-on-rails-4

Can't understand how Rails association with models works. Here is simple question:

There are two tables

products

```
id|   name  | status
1 | Tube    | 0
2 | Pillar  | 1
3 | Book    | 0
4 | Gum     | 1
5 | Tumbler | 2
```

statuses

```
status | name
0      | Unavailable
1      | In stock
2      | Discounted
```

With ~ same names for models and controllers.

I don't what to create new row in statuses table on every new product. And i want to show status name in erb. What should i write in models and in migration file (for example for which belong_to, has_one or has_many...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product should `belongs_to :status` and Status should `has_many :products` for a simple one-to-many association, and you aren't required to set a status for a product. In erb you'd use `<%= @product.status.name %>`. To set up those migrations, `create_table :products do |t| t.string :name; t.integer :status_id; end` and `create_table :statuses do |t| t.string :name; end`

[more information here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)

Answer (score 0):

First of all for in accordance with rails conventions you need to rename product.status to product.status_id.

product belongs_to :status
status has_many :products

Product.find(1).status.name should be 'Unavailable'

Answer (score 0):

If you understand the basics of relational database then it's pretty much the same thing.
When you say, `status belongs_to :product` and `product has_many :statuses`, it essentially means status table has a foreign key which you can use to retrieve all status rows for a given product id.

To establish this relationship, you'll need to create a new column `product_id` in your statuses table:

```
rails g migration AddProductIdToStatuses product_id:integer
```

Once done, add the following in your product.rb:

```
has_many :statuses
```

and this in your status.rb:

```
belongs_to :product
```

Comment: Or you can add a reference like said in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16354779/2197555