# Associating a status from a separate table - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display the status of a model Pack based on a model Status.

The number of possible statuses is small, while there are many packs and each has a status.

I expect the status table will also be referenced by other models at a later stage.

I've added this to routes:

```
resources :packs do
   resources :statuses
end
```

And added a:

```
has_one :status
```

to **packs.rb**.

When I try to call the following from the view:

```
<%= pack.status.status %>
```

I get the following controller error:

> *PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column statuses.pack_id does not exist*

Clearly, I don't have this set up right, but I don't want statuses to reference packs.

How do I remove this association?

I tried using:

**statuses.rb:**

```
has_many :battery_packs
```

But then I removed it, and the error persisted.

So it may be that I need to roll-back a migration or something, but I'm not sure how to check.

Comment: Does `pack` have `status_id`?

Comment: no, looks like i made  typo, the column is status only

Comment: If `pack` is intended to hold a foreign key to `status`, then `pack belongs_to :status`.

Comment: If you want have the status as model, then you will need set the associations as well. If you don't want this approach, then I suggest to make status as a column in packs and use enums in model

Comment: Does has_one also use the foreign key?  has_one felt more appropriate to this situation though I'm still trying to evaluate the similarity to this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409912/rails-association-with-models-and-migration

Comment: You should really take a look at the [has_one Association docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association). It's quite clear. `has_one` implies the foreign key is on the other (i.e., `status`) model, which is not what you say you want.

Comment: That was the doc that I was reading.  Though admittedly it's still not that clear to me (implicitly or otherwise).  However, belongs_to seems to be the preferred choice (and it is now working for me).  So I will go with that.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, the semantics can be a little non-intuitive. Added as an answer. Feel free to upvote/accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your foreign key for `status` is on `pack`, you want:

```
class Pack < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :status 
end
```

As mentioned in comments and stated in the docs, `has_one` implies that `status` would have a foreign key for `pack`, which is not what you want.