# Add a reference column migration in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

A user has many uploads. I want to add a column to the `uploads` table that references the `user`. What should the migration look like?

Here is what I have. I'm not sure if I should use (1) `:user_id, :int` or (2) `:user, :references`. I'm not even sure if (2) works. Just trying to do this the "rails" way.

```
class AddUserToUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :uploads, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Relevant question except for Rails 3. [Rails 3 migrations: Adding reference column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954969/rails-3-migrations-adding-reference-column)

Answer (score 810, accepted):

**Rails 4.x**

When you **already have** `users` and `uploads` tables and wish to **add a new relationship** between them.

All you need to do is: just generate a migration using the following command:

```
rails g migration AddUserToUploads user:references
```

Which will create a migration file as:

```
class AddUserToUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :uploads, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

Then, run the migration using `rake db:migrate`.
This migration will take care of adding a new column named `user_id` to `uploads` table (referencing `id` column in `users` table), PLUS it will also add an index on the new column.

**UPDATE [For Rails 4.2]**

Rails can’t be trusted to maintain referential integrity; *relational databases* come to our rescue here. What that means is that we can add foreign key constraints at the *database level* itself and ensure that database would reject any operation that violates this set referential integrity. As @infoget commented, **Rails 4.2** ships with native support for *foreign keys(referential integrity)*. It's not required but you might want to add foreign key(as it's very useful) to the reference that we created above.

To add foreign key to an *existing reference*, create a new migration to add a foreign key:

```
class AddForeignKeyToUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_foreign_key :uploads, :users
  end
end
```

To create a completely *brand new reference with a foreign key(in Rails 4.2)*, generate a migration using the following command:

```
rails g migration AddUserToUploads user:references
```

which will create a migration file as:

```
class AddUserToUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :uploads, :user, index: true
    add_foreign_key :uploads, :users
  end
end
```

This will add a new foreign key to the `user_id` column of the `uploads` table. The key references the `id` column in `users` table.

**NOTE:** This is in addition to adding a reference so you still need to **create a reference first then foreign key** (*you can choose to create a foreign key in the same migration or a separate migration file*). Active Record only supports single column foreign keys and currently only `mysql`, `mysql2` and `PostgreSQL` adapters are supported. Don't try this with other adapters like `sqlite3`, etc. Refer to [Rails Guides: Foreign Keys](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys) for your reference.

Comment: In many cases it's good to add foreign key as well. [add_foreign_key](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key) (Rails 4.2)

Comment: Isn't the convention to use plurals as the table name in migration? AddForeignKeyToUploads ?

Comment: @TaufiqMuhammadi Both singular & plural form work in this case. Rails takes care of detecting and normalizing the table name. I do agree that table name in pluralized form would be more intuitive here, even though both should work. Hence, the update. Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: Is it possible to override the index name (e.g. when the auto-generated one is too long) inline with a polymorphic t.references line w/ `index: true?`. The inline declaration is nice syntax sugar compared to to having a separate `add_index` line (where it's possible to specify `name: "index_name"`)

Comment: I believe you can do all in one line:
add_reference :uploads, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
@KirtiThorat

Comment: Now, if you use the special generator syntax for migrations, Rails 4.2 will automatically create the correct migration with foreign key constraints included. `rails g migration AddUserToUploads user:references` produces
`add_reference :uploads, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true` in the appropriate migration.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it but it's vital to understand that if you have to recreate your database it will fail due to the foreign key constraint. For instance if you backup your production database and then try to restore it on your development machine it **will** fail.

Comment: Use `...index: true, foreign_key: true` instead o line `add_foreign_key`.

Comment: Is there and similar special generator syntax for migrations to drop foreign key in rails 4.2?

Comment: @aksam `remove_reference :uploads, :user` would remove the associated column and index. You can verify this by checking `schema.rb`

Comment: Rails 4.2.3 appears to do this in one line by default. `rails g migration AddUserToUploads user:references` created a migration with `add_reference :uploads, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true` for me.

Comment: @KirtiThorat What happens if there is already `user_id` column in the `uploads` table - will `references` fail or ignore?

Comment: Why do we need both `foreign_key` and `t.reference`? Isn't `t.reference` essentially equivalent to `foriegn_key` + `index`?

Comment: Update to Rails 5: it generates the migration with the FK as a hash parameter `add_reference :merchants, :merchant_storefront, foreign_key: true`

Comment: Also for rails 5 onwards please refer to @Mirror318 answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39502978/4376810

Answer (score 232):

### Rails 5

You can still use this command to create the migration:

```
rails g migration AddUserToUploads user:references
```

The migration looks a bit different to before, but still works:

```
class AddUserToUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :uploads, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Note that it's `:user`, not `:user_id`

Comment: For name-spaced classes, like `Local::User` instead of `User` do something like `rails g migration AddLocalUserToUploads user:references`.

Comment: does this automatically add `:index`

Comment: @Zeke Yes, run the migration and check your schema, it should say something like `t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_uploads_on_user_id", using: :btree`

Comment: yeah, i got an "index exists" error when i manually added the add_index in migration :P @Mirror318

Comment: This is some next level rails magic. Been doing rails for years and didn't realise the migration name actually meant anything.

Comment: We should also add `belongs_to :user` in `Upload` class, so we can use `upload.user` to get the user instance.

Comment: @Mirror318 What if you already add have a `user_id` column on `uploads`? Will this error out or just update the column from `t.integer` to `t.references`?

Comment: @geoboy I'd personally much rather remove that column and add `t.references`, or if you have data you want to keep, rename `user_id` to something temporary, create `t.references`, copy the data over, then remove the temp column

Comment: @Mirror318 Thanks, could you elaborate more why? What does `t.reference` tells ActiveRecord which is different from `t.foreign_key` and an `index` separately?

Comment: @geoboy I don't know the exact differences (someone else might know...?), but this is a general case of "The Rails Way™", where the less manual work/customization, the better.

Comment: Can somebody help me out here? Am having an error in a case of a modular rails app engine based. When I generate this migration and run the migration, I get *relation “users” does not exist*. A using a mountable rails engine as a result of modularity.

Comment: @KaMok seems your comment looks like what I have. But PG relation error is what I get.

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi engines are a pain, I think when I was doing something with them I had to name space them e.g. `my_engine_users`

Answer (score 31):

if you like another alternate approach with `up` and `down` method try this:

```
  def up
    change_table :uploads do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
    end
  end

  def down
    change_table :uploads do |t|
      t.remove_references :user, index: true
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 21):

**Create a migration file**

```
rails generate migration add_references_to_uploads user:references
```

**Default foreign key name**

This would create a user_id column in uploads table as a foreign key

```
class AddReferencesToUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :uploads, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :uploads
end
```

upload model:

```
class Upload < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Customize foreign key name:**

```
add_reference :uploads, :author, references: :user, foreign_key: true
```

This would create an author_id column in the uploads tables as the foreign key.

user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :uploads, foreign_key: 'author_id'
end
```

upload model:

```
class Upload < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: How could I specify a field to be used as foreign key? Lets say I want to use as foreign key a unique string field instead of the row id. How's the migration syntax for that?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to use a field other than the row id.

`add_foreign_key :from_table, :to_table, column: :field  primary_key: "row_id"`

You might also want to index it, for performance reasons

Answer (score 19):

Just to document if someone has the same problem...

In my situation I've been using `:uuid` fields, and the above answers does not work to my case, because rails 5 are creating a column using `:bigint` instead `:uuid`:

```
add_reference :uploads, :user, index: true, type: :uuid
```

Reference: [Active Record Postgresql UUID](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#uuid)

Comment: It's also a lot clearer what's happening.  But yeah UUID should be standard now.

Answer (score 13):

**[Using Rails 5]**

Generate migration:

```
rails generate migration add_user_reference_to_uploads user:references
```

This will create the migration file:

```
class AddUserReferenceToUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :uploads, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Now if you observe the schema file, you will see that the uploads table contains a new field. Something like: `t.bigint "user_id"` or `t.integer "user_id"`.

Migrate database:

```
rails db:migrate
```

Comment: This answer seems to be duplicate of @Mirror318's answer. Please comment on above answer if you think something is missing from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Another syntax of doing the same thing is:

```
rails g migration AddUserToUpload user:belongs_to
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class MigrationName < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  disable_ddl_transaction!
  
  def change
    add_reference :uploads, :user, index: {algorithm: :concurrently}
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess you're adding an answer with Rails7-specific details. Would it make sense to add a word of explanation around what's new?

Comment: Rails adds an index non-concurrently to references by default, which blocks writes in Postgres. Make sure the index is added concurrently.