# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Products#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new to rails 4.I used nested attributes for multiple image upload.But i'm having few problems with this

im getting **ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Products#index**

***Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'pictures.product_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `pictures`.* FROM `pictures` WHERE `pictures`.`product_id` = 11*** error

**My models are as follows**

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
   has_attached_file :image
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :comments , dependent: :destroy
    has_many :pictures
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures 
end
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @product.comments.build
    @category_id = @product.category_id
    @category1 = Category.find_by(id: @category_id)
end
def new
    @product = current_user.products.build
    @product.pictures.build
end
def create
    @product = current_user.Product.new(product_params)
    @product.save
respond_to do |format|
  if @product.save
    format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :description, :reason, :user_id,:status,:category_id,pictures_attributes: [:image])
end

def correct_user
  @product = current_user.products.find_by(id:  params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url if @product.nil?
end
end
```

**Schema.rb**

```
 ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151226132302) do
create_table "pictures", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
t.string   "name",               limit: 255
t.integer  "price",              limit: 4
t.text     "description",        limit: 65535
t.text     "reason",             limit: 65535
t.integer  "user_id",            limit: 4
t.string   "image_file_name",    limit: 255
t.string   "image_content_type", limit: 255
t.integer  "image_file_size",    limit: 4
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
t.string   "status",             limit: 255
t.integer  "category_id",        limit: 4
t.integer  "product_id",         limit: 4
end
end
```

My migration file
**20151226132302_add_product_id_to_product.rb**

```
class AddProductIdToPictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      add_reference :pictures, :product, index: true
   end
   end
```

Even with above migration product_id is not added to pictures model.
Can somebody help me with this?
It will be helpful if someone can give me nice reference for **RAILS 4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> unknown attribute 'product_id'

Suggests you don't have the `product_id` column in your `pictures` table.

If you're using [`has_many` / `belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association), you'll need to set the [`foreign_key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) for your `belongs_to` model in its table:

[image]

If you don't have the `product_id` column in your `pictures` table, you'll need to use the following:

```
$ rails g migration AddProductIdToPictures

# db/migrate/add_product_id_to_pictures_________.rb
class AddProductIdToPictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      add_reference :pictures, :product, index: true
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

Ref: [Add a reference column migration in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815009/add-a-reference-column-migration-in-rails-4)

---

Another issue you may have is that you're using `.build` in the new method. I know that `new` and `build` have very little difference, but I was under the impression to use `new`:

```
def new
   @product = current_user.products.new
   @product.pictures.build
end
```

You've also got an error in your `create` action:

```
def create
    #NO - @product = current_user.Product.new(product_params) #-> cannot use constant

    #Should be this:
    @product = current_user.products.new
    @product.save
end
```