# rails creating relationships between 2 existing models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models:

```
Account
Profile
```

creating these models created 2 tables in the database:

```
accounts
profiles
```

now I want to add a relationship:

- each account can have many profiles
- each profile belongs to one account

I ran the following command:

```
rails g migration AddAccountToProfiles account:references
```

which created the following migration:

```
class AddAccountToProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :profiles, :account, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

now I'm a little confused:

why does the migration say `:profiles` and `:account`? Shouldn't it be `:accounts` (plural)?

also, after (or before) creating this migration, I have to add `belongs_to` and `has_many` in the appropriate model class right?

as a side question, is there a way to add `belongs_to` and `has_many` in the models, and from that information have rails generate the appropriate migration without me manually creating a migration with the `'rails g migration ...'` command?

Comment: [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22815259/1301840)

Comment: @lusketeer I actually read that answer and that's where I learned to use the migration command, but I want to understand the details of why singular/plural names are generated

Comment: as per [rails documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#highlighter_889766), the command will generate the migration file above, since you specified user:references, then it assumes to create `user_id` on `profiles` table, but you still need to add the relationships in the corresponding model files. when we use `:accounts` in migration file, it's referring to the table, `:account` is used as the name of the foreign key to be added onto the table along with suffix `_id`

Comment: @lusketeer you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [rails documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#highlighter_889766), the command

```
rails g migration AddAccountToProfiles account:references
```

will generate the migration file below

```
class AddAccountToProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :profiles, :account, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Since you specified `account:references`, then it assumes to create `account_id` on `profiles` table, but you still need to add the relationships in the corresponding model files.

When we use `:accounts` in migration file, it's referring to the table in the database, `:account` is used as the name of the foreign key to be added onto the table along with suffix `_id`

Also relevant information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815009/add-a-reference-column-migration-in-rails-4/22815259#22815259)

Answer (score 1):

The migration is correct, because a profile only belongs to one account. It should not be 'accounts'. The migration will place a `account_id` column onto the profiles table in order to make that connection.

After the migration, you still need to add `has_many` and `belongs_to`. In Rails, when defining a relationship, there are generally two steps 1) create the database migration 2) define the relation on the model class itself. You need to have both. In this case, Rails is looking for the `account_id` column on a profile (the default foreign key) to make the relationship between the two models.

And as for your last question, no, there is not a way to generate migrations after defining a `has_many`. You can use Rails generators to create the model itself `rails generate model ModelName` and define the relationship in that model; that will add the correct `belongs_to` and `has_many` into the generated model along with the migration. But in practice, it's generally better to create the migration and manually add `belongs_to` and `has_many` as needed so there's less of a chance of missing something.