# Rails migration with add_foreign_key: 'column "user_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

(Rails is version 5.0.0, Ruby 2.3.0p0)

I want to create an association between my Users table and Cards table. I've added `belongs_to :user` to the Cards model, and `has_many :cards` to the Users model, and created a migration with:

```
class AddUserIdToCard < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_foreign_key :cards, :users, column: :user_id
  end
end
```

When I run `rake db:migrate`, I receive the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "user_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "cards" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_8ef7749967"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("id")
```

Now I initially worked around this problem simply by adding `add_column :cards, :user_id, :integer` to the migration, but that doesn't really seem very tidy, and I'm worried about problems coming up later. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please mark the answer when you have a minute, since it is correct

Answer (score 3):

You're setting a foreign key for `cards` table with the column `user_id`. But you haven't created a reference yet. Create a reference and then add foreign key to maintain referential integrity. Rollback and modify your migration with

```
1    class AddUserIdToCard < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
2      def change
3        add_reference :cards, :users, index:true
4        add_foreign_key :cards, :users
5      end
6    end
```

Line 3 will create, in the `cards` table, a reference to `id` in the `users` table (by creating a `user_id` column in `cards`).

Line 4 will add a foreign key constraint to `user_id` at the database level.

For more, read [Add a reference column migration in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815009/add-a-reference-column-migration-in-rails-4)

Comment: Okay... I got a no method error for `add_references`, but I tried `add_reference` (singular) instead and that error went away.

However, I still got what looks like basically the same error:

`StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:`

`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "user_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "cards" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_8ef7749967"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("id")`

Comment: I am sorry. the method name is `add_reference` and not `add_references`. I'll update it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided is not accurate for Rails 5. Scroll to the [add_reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-migration) bit of the docs for more, but in the case of the above question, you would use:

```
    class AddUserIdToCard < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
      def change
        add_reference :cards, :users, foreign_key: true
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

In rails 6, I believe this is now

```
  def change
    add_column :cards, :user_id, :integer, index: true
    add_foreign_key :cards, :users
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class AddUserIdToCard < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_foreign_key :cards, :users, column: :user_id, primary_key: :"id", on_delete: :cascade
  end
end
```

Try this migration. I was facing the same problem then I fixed it.