# index: true vs foreign_key: true (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

Following a guide, I ran the following command:

```
rails g migration CreateSnippetsUsers snippet:belongs_to user:belongs_to
```

This created the following migration:

```
class CreateSnippetsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :snippets_users do |t|
      t.belongs_to :snippet, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

In the past I've seen the same thing, but with `index: true` instead of `foreign_key: true`. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815009/add-a-reference-column-migration-in-rails-4 possibly this will help

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Indexes**, **foreign keys** and **foreign keys *constraints*** are strictly related concepts in databases that are often confused or misunderstood.

**REFERENCES**
When you declare a **reference**, you're simply saying to include a column whose values should match those of another table (and in Rails you also get some useful methods to navigate through the associated models). In the example:

```rb
create_table :appointments do |t|
  t.references :student
end
```

the `appointments` table will have a column named `student_id` whose values should be in the pool of students' id values.

**INDEXES**
Since when you add a reference you will probably use that column often, you may (and probably should!) also tell you database to boost the look up speed using the reference column. You can do this with the option `index: true` (which by the way is a default option in the `reference` method since Rails 5). Indexes have few drawbacks, the main being a larger memory consumption.

**FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS**
From what said so far, `reference column` and `foreign column` are synonyms. But do you remember when I said that a reference column's values *should* match those of another table? If you simply declare a reference, it's your responsibility to ensure that a matching row on the referenced table exists, or someone will end up doing nonsense actions like creating appointments for non-existing students. This is an example of *database integrity*, and fortunately there are some mechanisms that will grant a stronger level of integrity. These mechanisms are called *' database constraints'*. What the option `foreign_key: true` does is exactly to add this kind of constraint on the reference column, to reject any entry whose foreign key values are not in the referenced table.

Database integrity is a complex task, growing in difficulty with the database's complexity. You probably should add also other kind of constraints, like using they keywords `dependent: :destroy` in your class to ensure that when you delete a student, all of its existing appointments are also destroyed.

As usual, here's a RTFM link: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 19):

Index improve speed of data retrieval operations on database tables. When we write `index: true` to any column, it adds a database index to this column. For example I was creating a table:

```
    create_table :appointments do |t|
      t.references :student, index: true 
    end
```

It will create `student_id` column in `appointments` table.

A foreign key have different use case, it is a relationship between tables. It allow us to declare an index in one table that is related to an index in another table and also some constraints are placed.The database enforces the rules of this relationship to maintain referential integrity. For example we have two table `profiles` and `educations`, and a profile may have many educations.

```
create_table :educations do |t| 
  t.belongs_to :profile, index: true, foreign_key: true
end
```

Now we have `profile_id` column in `educations` table which is foreign key of `profiles` table. It prevents a record from being entered into the `educations` table unless it contains a `profile_id` value that exists in the `profiles` table. So referential integrity will be maintained.

Comment: Woudn't `t.references :student` create `student_id` column in `appointments` table? If so, what does `index: true` do?

Comment: index: true does indexing here.

Comment: You don't need to add an index with `references` - it's added by default. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48557905/312342