# How to convert an ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation into an array in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I convert an `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` into an array of Rails model instances?

I have code that is in an `after_save` hook like this:

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :likee, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'likee_id'
  belongs_to :liker, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'liker_id'

  after_save :mutual_like?

  private

  def mutual_like?
    if liker.likes.where(likee: liker) // returns collection proxy but I want to return an array of model instances so that I can create another model

    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way to return an array of instances instead?

Table for reference:

```
  create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "liker_id",      null: false
    t.integer  "likee_id",      null: false
    ...
  end
```

I believe the problem is that Rails is not associating the models based on the foreign key of likee_id / liker_id.

Comment: this `if liker.likes.where(likee: liker)` returns a bool value, it can not return a `collection proxy`

Comment: I've also saved `liker.likes.where(likee: liker)` to a variable and it's a collection proxy

Comment: use some loading method to get an AR: `liker.likes.where(likee: liker) .all`

Comment: Returns the same thing.

Comment: `liker.likes.where(likee: liker).first`?

Comment: I then get this: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`. I'm thinking my foreign key is somehow messed up here.

Answer (score 8):

Try [ActiveRecord#to_a](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_a).

`liker.likes.where(likee: liker).to_a`

> **`to_a()`** *public*
>
> Converts relation objects to Array.

Comment: I tried that and I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column likes.user_id does not exist`

Comment: You need a [migration](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) that adds the database columns for `liker_id` and `likee_id`. Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815009/add-a-reference-column-migration-in-rails-4

Comment: Seems like your problem in in the definition of the association `has_many :likes` in the `User` class. You need to specify the foreign_key there too.