# Add a reference column migration in Rails 5

Tags: rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

A user has many uploads. I want to add a column to the uploads table that references the user. What should the migration look like?

Related question for Rails 3: [Rails 3 migrations: Adding reference column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954969/rails-3-migrations-adding-reference-column)

Related question for Rails 4: [Add a reference column migration in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22815009/972128)

Related question for Rails 6: [How to add reference column migration in Rails 6 with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60080860/how-to-add-reference-column-migration-in-rails-6-with-sqlite)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As with prior versions of Rails, you may use the following command to create the migration:

`rails g migration AddUserToUploads user:references`

Unlike prior versions of Rails, the migration looks like:

```
class AddUserToUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :uploads, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```